# Spring Boot WebSecurity not ignoring file uploaded from client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring boot project with Configuration WebSecurity like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
}
```

After I started project I can normally access file in resources folder by web browser. Example: ***http://localhost:8080/resources/file1.css***

But the issue is: I have a feature use to upload file from client to server. If I upload a file from client ex: ***file2.css*** to resources folder in server. I can not access file by address ***http://localhost:8080/resources/file2.css*** until I restart the project, ***file2.css*** has been upload successfully and existed in the resources folder but it response error unauthorized

```
<UnauthorizedException>
    <error>unauthorized</error>
    <error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description>
</UnauthorizedException>
```

If I restart server project ***http://localhost:8080/resources/file2.css*** can access normally.

**Is there any way I can bypass WebSecurity right after uploading the file?**

Please help, thanks so much!

Comment: >> If I restart server project http://localhost:8080/resources/file2.css can access normally. This could actually mean your resources folder is part of the jar built, not the way you are trying to access it.

Comment: I think about it and decided to put the file in different location then read it's content with another api written on the controller. it seems to work fine but I need a handler to pass the file path as an api parameter and read from there to the appropriate file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies with the fact that you are trying to upload the files to a folder in the classpath; I would suggest to use a different location to upload files and configure that location as a resource location and access using a resource handler.

For example, if you plan to upload files to /usr/local/upload, then you can configure

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/upload/**")
          .addResourceLocations("file:/usr/local/upload");
     } 
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how to write this function. I search in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but don't see addResourceHandlers to Override. Can you detail it?

Comment: you need to override addResourceHandlers from WebMvcConfigurer.